How do I remove debris suspended between the top and the bottom of the pool?
How do I get debris floating in the pool between the top and the bottom? I have a Betta skimmer that constantly runs over the top. I have a vacuum to clean the bottom. The middle area between the top and the bottom has debris suspended in it. How do I get rid of that debris regularly?

Is it round and above ground?

@isherwood  "It's a Betta that..."  It's a solar powered floating skimmer that run over the surface of the pool. Think of  a Roomba vacuum cleaner but for the surface of a pool.  You probably don't see a whole lot of them in ST. Cloud.

True. They'd get tangled in the lily pads.

That debris will eventually sink where it can be vacuumed or will float so the skimmer can get it. To get rid of it regularly,daily, get a net and a long pole and just go back and forth. That's what the pool guys and gals do.

Agreed. In larger pools there is often a bottom drain at the lowest point which maintains some downward circulation and catches most of the stuff that is actually suspended in the water. But the pool vacuum will do the same thing, just not as continuously, and vacuuming is usually needed anyway to catch the stuff that the currents don't sweep to this drain. If the water is getting cloudy, that is a water chemistry problem, and a test kit will tell you how to adjust to clear it.

Buy flocculant, follow floc's instructions, and vacuum the bottom of your pool.

You would normally run a pool pump with filter to circulate the water and remove particles from it.  Heavier debris will precipitate to the bottom to be vacuumed.  Bulkier, lighter-than-water debris will float on top for the skimmer.  The pump circulates the water, which may push debris to the top (skimmer vents) or bottom (main drain), or the debris may get caught in the filter.
How Does a Pool Pump/Filter System Work?  No affiliation.  I found it on the internet.  It has pictures and diagrams.  Warning:  they sell pools with filtration systems.  They want to upsell you on heating and salt water pools.
Redditor considering a robot vacuum
